# Add image to UISegmentedControl from another controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

`MainViewController` contains `UISegmentedControl` with 3 segments.

`SliderSubViewController` contains a `UISlider` and `-(void) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender`

I want to add a code like this in `SliderSubViewController.m` but I'm stuck on how to access the `UISegmentedControl` and add an image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

mainController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];


[minPrisSlider addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) 
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{

NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)(minPrisSlider.value + 0.5); // Round the number.
[minPrisSlider setValue:index animated:NO];

int progressAsInt =(int)(minPrisSlider.value + 0.5f);
NSString *newText =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d,-",progressAsInt];
minPrisText.text = newText;

if (minPrisSlider.value != 70) {
    /*mainController.segmentedControl add main bundle image named "CheckboxChecked.png" 
   to current segment*/
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added SliderViewController as subview on MainViewController, One approach you can try is to just declare object of MainViewController in SliderViewController write @property and @synthesize, dont allocate it and while adding SliderView as subview just assign it as

sliderviewcontrollerObject.mainViewControllerObject = self;

now you can access segmentedControl from sliderview ass self.mainViewControllerObject.segmentedbar

Also you can try [delegate](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/) approach.